# How to store a big floating point number in python variable?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

In python why result become zero when i multiply anyother value with 5.55375797812e+28  .
But we all Know Python accept a very big range value.

Comment: [`decimal.Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#decimal-objects), your question is however off topic for stackoverflow as you are asking to find some tool for you.

Comment: its not working bro i used it......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the built-in `decimal` library.

```
import decimal

decimal.getcontext().prec = 46 # Change 46 to the precision you want.
result = decimal.Decimal(1.6) / decimal.Decimal(7)

print(result)
Decimal('0.2285714285714285841168345671446461762700762068')
```

Keep in mind that when you have to use the set precision you always need to enclose the number in `decimal.Decimal()` and you will always get `Decimal()` returned.