# Very big number with floating point in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have done some research throughout SO and I believe this is not a duplicate of [How to get largest possible precision? (Python - Decimal)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53660036/how-to-get-largest-possible-precision-python-decimal) or [Arithmetic precision problems with large numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41665588/arithmetic-precision-problems-with-large-numbers) or [How to store a big floating point number in python variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36532057/how-to-store-a-big-floating-point-number-in-python-variable)

Let's say that I have this number: `11400361308443875328.123123123123`

What data type can I use to store this in Python? I have tried `float`, `decimal` and the result it gives me:

```
x = Decimal('11400361308443875328.123123123123123') + Decimal('11400361308443875328.123123123123123')
print("{:12f}".format(x))
# 22800722616887750656.24624625

y = float(11400361308443875328.123123123123) + float(11400361308443875328.123123123123)
print("{:12f}".format(y))
# 22800722616887750656.000000

z = Decimal('0.123123123123123') + Decimal('0.123123123123123')
print("{:12f}".format(z))
# 0.246246246246246
```

I need the degree of precision that z has. How should I store this big number with floating precision so that I can do some mathematical operations on it? Is there some trick on how I can do this?

For the question on why I need this high degree of precision: this is a question from a coding challenge (not the actual question), and the submission is graded with a leeway of +- 10^-6 precision

Comment: `x = Decimal('11400361308443875328.123123123123')`. Without making it a string, Decimal has no chance to save the precision as the number it gets has already lost the required precision.

Comment: Oops sorry that was my mistake, let me fix the question. But you make a good point there @matszwecja

Comment: If the number of floating point digits is the same in both numbers, you can remove the decimal separator via string manipulation and add the resulting integers (integers are arbitrary size in python). You can then simply add the decimal separator back in, again, using string manipulation.

Comment: This question is answered in the *question* at the linked duplicate. The problem is a simple matter of reading the documentation, so I figured it should be easy to refer to a duplicate; but that's the best I could manage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `decimal`'s default precision is not enough, you can change it by modifying value of `getcontext().prec` - https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#module-decimal

```
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext

getcontext().prec = 50

x = Decimal('11400361308443875328.123123123123123') + Decimal('11400361308443875328.123123123123123123')
print(x) # 22800722616887750656.246246246246246123
```